# Update Windows Form Application UI from a Website [SCREEN-SCRAPING]

Tags: c#, javascript, webclient

I have Windows Forms Application that Updates its GUI from a website using WebClient's GET Requests; However some of these values are updated in the web page using JavaScript so user don't have to keep refreshing the page to get them. How could i make my program get those values without having to keep sending new GET Requests.

Comment: You need to elaborate more on this, can you provide some code that shows how you're currently tracking things. I "think" you're talking about async tracking.

Comment: Some pages updates values using java script so you don't have to repeatedly refresh the page to see the most updated values. so i want to get those values without having to make multiple GET requests.

Comment: I'm confused - you want to do this in the web client (javascript), or in another app with C#?

Comment: OK, now I'm confused. What you seem to be describing is a scenario where the C# is not server-side code. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Imaging you have a clock on a webpage how could you keep tracking of this clock and render the time on the c# app {ofcourse you will not keep making GET Requests}

Comment: What does it have to do with javascript?

Comment: OK, I think I'm getting it. You have a C# app that has no javascript. You get data into your app by screen scraping another website. But one of the pages on that site has data you want that's updated by javascript. Is this correct? If so, modify you description and add the terms "screen-scraping" etc to make it clear to others what you mean.

Comment: Yea this is what i am doing getting the data for my windows forms application from a website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do exactly what you want is to reverse engineer the javascript that updates the values on the page you're scraping. Beyond that, I'm afraid what you're doing is the best we can do.

On the plus side, javascript is nothing more than plain text source code so you can take a peek at it. But the legality of doing so depends on where you are. In most places including the US, just looking at the online code is legal. Reproducing it is not. But as the judge in the Oracle vs Google case said: it doesn't make sense to apply copyright to a single function (I'm paraphrasing, he said "range_check" not "a single function").

If the javascript is obfuscated then copy paste it into a pretty printer. Just Google for "javascript pretty printer". There are lots of them online.

Answer (score 1):

You say that you want to be able to do something in C# like you do in JavaScript, but you don't want to have to "keep sending new GET Requests".  The thing is, that's *exactly* what the JavaScript is doing.  It just happens to be doing it asynchronously behind the scenes.  You can do the very same thing with C#.  The JavaScript is just doing GET or POST requests behind the scenes, and you can do the very same requests with C#.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can simply set a timer to GetElementById from a hidden web browser